# Object keys version typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working in angular do you know what this means (inside `.map`)? Is there another way to code more legibly?

```
this.formattedErrors = Object.keys(errorList.errors || {})
    .map(key => `${key} ${errorList.errors[key]}`);
```

Comment: How much more legible to do you want it? Pretty clear what's happening - iterate the object, return a concatenated result of `key value`

Comment: On that basis, `Object.entries(errorList.errors || {}).map(([key, value]) => \`${key} ${value}\`)` is maybe more intentful.

Comment: It is advisable that you learn JS basics before working with serious frameworks. This is just normal array map usage, can't be simpler. Check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @dfsq if anything template strings and lambas are simpler than Maps

Comment: [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) explains Arrow functions, and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) explains Template literals.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you very much for the links

Comment: @McTwist - You are welcome. :-)